# Running Go from the command line nested JSON

Tags: unix, go, command-line

I can think of workarounds on how to get this working however I'm interested in finding out if there's a solution to this specific problem.

I've got a go program which requires a json string arguement:

```
go run main.go "{ \"field\" : \"value\" }"
```

No problems so far. However, am I able to run from the command line if one of the json values is another json string?

```
go run main.go "{ \"json-string\" : \"{\"nestedfield\" : \"nestedvalue\"}\" }"
```

It would seem that adding escape characters incorrectly matches up the opening and closing quotes. Am I minuderstanding how this is done or is it (and this is the side I'm coming down on) simply not possible?

To reiterate, this is a question that has piqued my curiosity - I'm aware of alternative approaches - I'm hoping for input related to this specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback from wiredeye I went down the argument route instead. I've modified the program to run on:

```
go run main.go field:value field2:value json-string:"{\"nestedfield\":nestedvalue}"
```

I can then iterate over the os.Args and get the nested json within my program. I'm not using flags directly as I don't know the amount of inputs into the program which would have required me to use duplicate flags (not supported) or parse the flag to a collection (doesn't seem to be supported).

Thanks wiredeye

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put your json config to the file and provide config file name to your application using [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It led to my eventual solution